Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS shutdown not finishing on Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 460
I decided to give Ubuntu another shot and installed it alongside an existing Windows installation following this guide on my machine.
Unfortunately, start-up is really slow and shutdown is not completed (GUI and terminal), while reboot works as expected, albeit slowly.
I would be thankful for some help in identifying possible culprits from the output obtained with journalctl -b -1 -r | grep systemd and suggestions for remediation of the issue.
